# Why the reference count of small int are bigger

Tags: python, python-2.7, reference-counting

I am not able to understand why the reference count of small integer are all greater than 1.

Could some one please explain or point me to the right docs.

Thanks.

```
>>> import sys
>>> for i in range(100):
...     i, sys.getrefcount(i)
...
(0, 383)
(1, 577)
(2, 83)
(3, 27)
(4, 66)
(5, 22)
(6, 20)
(7, 21)
(8, 41)
(9, 18)
(10, 22)
(11, 18)
(12, 14)
(13, 14)
(14, 14)
(15, 14)
(16, 37)
(17, 14)
(18, 13)
(19, 14)
(20, 13)
(21, 13)
(22, 13)
(23, 14)
(24, 13)
(25, 14)
(26, 13)
(27, 13)
(28, 13)
(29, 14)
(30, 14)
```

Comment: probably because the sys library (and other parts of the python VM use the small int objects too - the fact that 0 & 1 are by far the most used, suggests that code is really using these.

Answer (score 1):

probably because the sys library (and other parts of the python VM use the small int objects too - the fact that 0 & 1 are by far the most used, suggests that code is really using these.

I can't point you to the docs, and I wouldn't think that it is something that is the same between different versions of python.

I think it counts as an interesting result of the python implementation, rather than anything that actually matters.